# gcloud AR cannot resolve dependency

Tags: maven, google-artifact-registry

I pushed artifact to my private gcloud artifact registry (maven format). Now I am trying to add a dependency from the remote AR repo. I

- added `<repository>` and dependencies to my `pom.xml`
- i authenticated by command line

After this i still got
`Cannot resolve dependency` error

I also tried to authenticate by adding environment variable key. That also didn't work out. Is there anything I am missing? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE : I removed maven caches and re-imported dependencies. I get

`Could not find artifact com.company.group:artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in artifact-registry (artifactregistry://europe-maven.pkg.dev/project-name/repo-name)`

UPDATE : I had old artifacts in another repository, I published my new artifacts into that repository, and imported everything from that repo to my project. All artifacts were successfully imported except the new one... I guess something is wrong with the new artifact.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I added in the pom.xml the definition of the remote repository, also added maven-wagon extension. But still not working - Am I missing something? I can see all the dependencies in C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository - but the project cannot solve theme in Inteliij.